# how to save photo in gallery folder in android using xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**How to save photo in gallery folder?** I am using ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2 and Xam.Media.Plugin

code is working fine, but it saving in location: /data/user/0/com.companyname.projectname/cache/cropped3243.png

**i want to save it in gallery folder. how can i do this?**

```
protected async void TapGestureRecognizerCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

                ImageSource TempimageFile = null;
                new ImageCropper()
                {
                    PageTitle = "Crop Photo",
                    AspectRatioX = 3, // 
                    CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle, //Cropt shape
                    SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",  // Pop up Title
                    TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",       // Popup - 1st option 
                    PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library", //Popup - 2nd option
                    Success = (imageFile) =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            TempimageFile = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);

                            DisplayAlert("test", "te: " + TempimageFile, "OK");
                            ImageURL.Source = TempimageFile;
                        });
                    }
                }.Show(this);
        }
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be an option to do this in the plugin

Comment: There is no gallery folder on an Android device

Comment: @jason, i can save in gallery using Xam.Media.Plugin only, but it doesnt have crop option...  ImageCropper.Forms.Fix.v2 has crop option but no save to gallery

Comment: any idea how can i do this? maybe different plugin? any ref links would be helpful

Comment: it's an open source plugin, modify it to do what you want and submit a PR

Comment: yeah i am new to xamarin and def wont be able to modify that plugin, I barely got this to working with guide. and no iidea what is PR... thanks anyways tho

Comment: Is `Directory` working in this [usage](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage)? And it is merged to Xamarin Essential since last Nov by the way.

Comment: yes, xam.media.plugin has directory to save in gallery but it doesnt have cropping for android

Comment: Maybe you could save it to the gallery by yourself after crop the picture.

Answer (score 0):

For example,you could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)  to call the natvie method to save it to the system photo album.

create a interface in your forms project:

```
public interface ISaveToGallery
{
    void Save(string filePath,string fileName);
}
```

then in you Android project:

```
class SaveToGallery: ISaveToGallery
{
    public void Save(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
          MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver,
                filePath, fileName, null);
    }
}
```

the call it like:

```
protected async void TapGestureRecognizerCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            ImageSource TempimageFile = null;
            new ImageCropper()
            {
                PageTitle = "Crop Photo",
                AspectRatioX = 3, // 
                CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle, //Cropt shape
                SelectSourceTitle = "Select source",  // Pop up Title
                TakePhotoTitle = "Take Photo",       // Popup - 1st option 
                PhotoLibraryTitle = "Photo Library", //Popup - 2nd option
                Success = (imageFile) =>
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        TempimageFile = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);

                        DisplayAlert("test", "te: " + TempimageFile, "OK");
                        ImageURL.Source = TempimageFile;
                        DependencyService.Get<ISaveToGallery>().Save(imageFile,"your file name");
                    });
                }
            }.Show(this);
    }
```